# How do I parse commands from a text file in C#?

Tags: c#, parsing, linked-list, file-read

I am creating an application for my C# class in school that reads commands in from text file and displays the results in the console. Basically there will be commands in the file that should add a node and delete a node from a singly linked list. So if in the input file it reads I:1, I:7 it would output Node1:1 and Node2:7 to the console.

I know how to parse a file to display things like hello world, etc. But I am unsure as to how I would parse a file to look for a specific string and then output results based on that string (in this case appending and deleting nodes from a list). Is there any resources on how one would do that?

This is what I have for my program so far:

```
public class LinkedList {    
Node head; //the head of list

  public class Node {

     public int data;
     public Node next;

     //constructor
     public Node(int d) { 
         data = d; 
           next = null;
       } //end of constructor
   }

public void printList() { //traversing list and printing the contents starting from head(1)
Node n = head;
while (n != null) {
    Console.Write(n.data + " ");
    n = n.next;
  }
}

public void push(int new_data) {

Node new_node = new Node(new_data); //allocate new node, put in data

new_node.next = head;   //make next of new node as head

head = new_node; //move the head to point to new node

}

//main method to create a linked list with 3 nodes
public static void Main(String[] args) {

//starting with an empty list
LinkedList llist = new LinkedList();

llist.head = new Node(1);
Node second = new Node(2);
Node third = new Node(3);
//now 3 nodes have been allocated. head, second, and third
llist.head.next = second; //linking the head (1st) with the second node. these are both now linked.
second.next = third; //linking second with third. now linked. all 3 are linked now

    llist.printList(); 
}

   } //end of class program
```

Comment: You're too far from your goal; you have to [break your big problem into simpler problems](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/). For example, I don't see you parsing a file anywhere. Learn how to open text files first. Then learn how to scan text files line-by-line. Then search for delimiters like `:` in your lines. Then learn how to extract tokens like numbers from your lines.

Comment: And, once you get through @DourHighArch's steps, document what your grammar will be (so far we only know what "I:N" (where N is numeric) means as a token).  Write it all out.  Then learn how to use regular expressions to parse things (for example, learn what `(?<token>I:(?<num>\d+))` means as a regular expression)

Comment: Your understanding seems backwards. You don't parse a file looking for specific strings, because you want to execute the commands in order from the file. Instead, you process the file (presumably line by line, possibly word by word) and then parse each line to determine what command is represented. You have to break up the input file based on how commands are separated, then parse each command.